# Analog sound output is not available

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

Last night we had a power failure. My UPS died before I was aware. When I rebooted I had no sound on Ubuntu. It is a dual boot machine and everything works on the other OS.
It is an Intel NUC10i5FNH.

In settings the only sound option offered is the HDMI port. The analog speaker/headphone out is not available and very dead. (Also,there are very few options offered on my machine compared to what I have seen online posted by trouble shooters. I see "input" "output" "sound effect" "applications" tabs on other people's settings images.)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOL1a.png)

I have tried many of the suggestions online like killing or purging pulseaudio or "sudo apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio" and
"sudo alsa force-reload" as well as lots of other suggested solutions. Nothing has worked.

Here is what Alsamixer looks like. There seems to be lots missing, although I notice the sound card is recognized. As I said, things work fine on the other OS, so it is not a hardware problem.

[Alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maYbh.png)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can restore my sound?

Comment: If I have a power outage, I tend to `fsck` (file system check) first before attempting to boot it (ie. from *live* media) and especially making changes..   If you did that, you didn't mention it (and just complicated things) as I expect system to boot normally post-fsck.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not used anything Linux in about 8 years, and I was not very good with the system in the first place. I would not know how to do a file system check. But I could figure it out. Is it too late?